# Pandas - convert column values to sequencial integers

Tags: python, pandas

In this `pandas`df, how do I change all datetime values in column 'date' below:

```
                   date  cases
0   2020-01-22T00:00:00Z      0
1   2020-01-23T00:00:00Z      0
2   2020-01-24T00:00:00Z      0
3   2020-01-25T00:00:00Z      0
4   2020-01-26T00:00:00Z      0
5   2020-01-27T00:00:00Z      0
6   2020-01-28T00:00:00Z      0
7   2020-01-29T00:00:00Z      0
8   2020-01-30T00:00:00Z      0
9   2020-01-31T00:00:00Z      0
10  2020-02-01T00:00:00Z      0
11  2020-02-02T00:00:00Z      0
12  2020-02-03T00:00:00Z      0
13  2020-02-04T00:00:00Z      0
14  2020-02-05T00:00:00Z      0
15  2020-02-06T00:00:00Z      0
16  2020-02-07T00:00:00Z      0
17  2020-02-08T00:00:00Z      0
18  2020-02-09T00:00:00Z      0
19  2020-02-10T00:00:00Z      0
20  2020-02-11T00:00:00Z      0
21  2020-02-12T00:00:00Z      0
22  2020-02-13T00:00:00Z      0
23  2020-02-14T00:00:00Z      0
24  2020-02-15T00:00:00Z      0
25  2020-02-16T00:00:00Z      0
26  2020-02-17T00:00:00Z      0
27  2020-02-18T00:00:00Z      0
28  2020-02-19T00:00:00Z      0
29  2020-02-20T00:00:00Z      0
30  2020-02-21T00:00:00Z      0
31  2020-02-22T00:00:00Z      0
32  2020-02-23T00:00:00Z      0
33  2020-02-24T00:00:00Z      0
34  2020-02-25T00:00:00Z      0
35  2020-02-26T00:00:00Z      1
36  2020-02-27T00:00:00Z      1
37  2020-02-28T00:00:00Z      1
38  2020-02-29T00:00:00Z      2
39  2020-03-01T00:00:00Z      2
40  2020-03-02T00:00:00Z      2
41  2020-03-03T00:00:00Z      2
42  2020-03-04T00:00:00Z      4
43  2020-03-05T00:00:00Z      4
44  2020-03-06T00:00:00Z     13
45  2020-03-07T00:00:00Z     13
46  2020-03-08T00:00:00Z     20
47  2020-03-09T00:00:00Z     25
48  2020-03-10T00:00:00Z     31
49  2020-03-11T00:00:00Z     38
50  2020-03-12T00:00:00Z     52
51  2020-03-13T00:00:00Z    151
52  2020-03-14T00:00:00Z    151
53  2020-03-15T00:00:00Z    162
54  2020-03-16T00:00:00Z    200
55  2020-03-17T00:00:00Z    321
56  2020-03-18T00:00:00Z    372
57  2020-03-19T00:00:00Z    621
58  2020-03-20T00:00:00Z    793
59  2020-03-21T00:00:00Z   1021
60  2020-03-22T00:00:00Z   1546
61  2020-03-23T00:00:00Z   1924
62  2020-03-24T00:00:00Z   2247
63  2020-03-25T00:00:00Z   2554
64  2020-03-26T00:00:00Z   2985
65  2020-03-27T00:00:00Z   3417
66  2020-03-28T00:00:00Z   3904
67  2020-03-29T00:00:00Z   4256
68  2020-03-30T00:00:00Z   4579
69  2020-03-31T00:00:00Z   5717
70  2020-04-01T00:00:00Z   6836
71  2020-04-02T00:00:00Z   8044
```

In order to end up with the following sequence?

```
date  cases
0        0
1        0
2        0
3        0
4        0
5        0
6        0
7        0
8        0
9        0
10       0
11       0
12       0
13       0
14       0
15       0
16       0
17       0
18       0
19       0
20       0
21       0
22       0
23       0
24       0
25       0
26       0
27       0
28       0
29       0
30       0
31       0
32       0
33       0
34       0
35       1
36       1
37       1
38       2
39       2
40       2
41       2
42       4
43       4
44      13
45      13
46      20
47      25
48      31
49      38
50      52
51     151
52     151
53     162
54     200
55     321
56     372
57     621
58     793
59    1021
60    1546
61    1924
62    2247
63    2554
64    2985
65    3417
66    3904
67    4256
68    4579
69    5717
70    6836
71    8044
```

Comment: your expected output shows you want to drop the date column? in that case `df = df.drop('date',axis=1)` works

Comment: No I’d like to keep the column ‘date’ with a sequence of integers rather than having an index

Comment: `df['date'] = np.arange(len(df))`?

Comment: rather than having an index? any specific reason you dont want the index? For not having to index you would have to convert the dataframe into string using `to_string()` after doing what @QuangHoang says , but that would not allow you for future pandas operations since you will lose the Dataframe type , if you want to directly export to excel or csv , you can do `index=False` while exporting

Comment: no I'd prefer to keep the index and replace date values with sequencial integers as well

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I am wrong, but this is what you're searching:

```
df['date'] = df.index
```